# Django-CMS and multiple menus

Tags: python, django, django-cms, django-mptt

I have a number of top level pages that need splitting into two different menus. Using Django and Django-CMS what would the best way to  do this?

I have been reading through a number of Google threads and the most common suggestion is nesting the pages under sub headings with a custom id. The menu then could be extracted using the function **show_menu_below_id**. While this method works the URL is altered to match the page hierarchy, which I would like to avoid..  I know there are methods to fix this problem but they have their own issues such as FLAT_URLS (alters all urls and is being retired) and overwrite-url - but this is manual and not wanted.

Thanks for any help or suggestions..

**Menu1**

```
HOME
B
C
```

**Menu2**

```
D
E
F
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go the show_menu_below_id way in combination with overwrite the url. Not nice but a very edge case.

Comment: I don't think it is what he wants: " I know there are methods to fix this problem but they have their own issues such as FLAT_URLS (alters all urls and is being retired) and overwrite-url - but this is manual and not wanted."

Comment: Pretty much, i know of these methods but would rather find a "better" way of doing it.

Comment: How would the optimal way in your opinion look like? Maybe i can help ;)

Comment: Have you used Wordpress? I would of thought a menu customisation option like that would exist. I have written my own method for doing it now, but I am new at Python and it feels like a hack.